# Access file from one folder of a bucket to another folder of the same bucket in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an Amazon S3 bucket. Inside the bucket are two folders:

- In the first folder there is an `index.html` file
- In the second bucket there is a `.js` file

How do I access the `.js` file in the second bucket from the `index.html` file in first bucket?

### index.html

```
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/folder2/array.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Display JS Array"/>
    <script>
        go();
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

### array.js

```
`function go(){
 var array = new Array();
 array[0] = "Red";
 array[1] = "Blue";
 array[3] = "Green";
 for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    document.write("<li>" + array[i] + "<br />");
 }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could **use the full path** to the file.

For example, if your bucket is called `bucket-name-2` and is in the Sydney region, the link to the `.js` file would be:

```
https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/bucket-name-2/array.js
```

(These URLs are displayed in the Amazon S3 management console.)

If both buckets are in the same region, you could probably refer to the file via:

```
src=/bucket-name-2/array.js
```

This is because they would share the same DNS name, but would vary on the bucket name.

If you have activated **static website hosting**, the URL would look like:

```
http://my-bucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/array.js
```

Comment: I tried accessing the one file from another file in the same bucket but I am getting permissions issue. Do you know what I am doing wrong. I used the complete path as mentioned by you.

Comment: @ManinderSingh Please create a new question with full details, rather than asking via a comment on an old question.